# Magento2 doesn't reindex

Tags: magento2, reindex

I added 2000 + products for magento2 , but Magento2 doesn't reindex index.

Run the reindex command `bin/magento indexer:reindex`
successfully. But my store's front doesn't display product.

My Magento 2 version is 2.0.7 , PHP 7.0.8 ,mysql 5.6

*var/log*

```
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4c6b6eeafea885c0042386fe963c20026: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_40a98983867a1770682b48d9a0ad63441: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exi$
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist $
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links$
[2016-09-02 13:02:02] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'store.settings.currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'stor$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.INFO: SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_custom_use_parent_settings.value_id > 0, at_custom_use_parent_settings.value, at_custom_use_parent_settings_default.valu$
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_custom_use_parent_settings_default` ON (`at_custom_use_parent_settings_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_custo$
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_custom_use_parent_settings` ON (`at_custom_use_parent_settings`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_custom_use_parent_set$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_46f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_3e6fe115ba31d500509103893a62701cf: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'no$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.rig$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_adminhtml_STORE1_36f1b068ec7ccf4878f9284dd1137afd1: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4a456e24e9e0ef145439d526f18fb8b48: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.INFO: Cache file with merged layout: LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_4c6690f29cb80c2b881a7311e8632bc3e: Please correct the XML data and try again.  [] []
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.link' tries to reorder itself towards 'top.links', but their parents are different: 'header.links$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'store.settings.currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'stor$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.price' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.review', but their parents are different: 'prod$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.price.final' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.sku', but their parents are different: 'produc$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'product.info.social' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.overview', but their parents are different: 'p$
[2016-09-02 13:02:03] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.addtocart.paypal', but their parents are different:$
```

*debug.log*

```
2016-09-02 13:04:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_customer_grid_flat_3"},"is_exception":fa$
[2016-09-02 13:04:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_customer_grid_flat_4"},"is_exception":fa$
[2016-09-02 13:04:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_customer_grid_flat_1"},"is_exception":fa$
[2016-09-02 13:04:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_customer_grid_flat_2"},"is_exception":fa$
[2016-09-02 13:04:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_customer_grid_flat_3"},"is_exception":fa$
[2016-09-02 13:04:02] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_customer_grid_flat_4"},"is_exception":fa$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category","catalog_product"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_category","catalog_product"],"mode":"matchingAnyTag"},$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_1"},"is_ex$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_2"},"is_ex$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_3"},"is_ex$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_4"},"is_ex$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_1"},"is_ex$
[2016-09-02 13:04:32] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"DB_PDO_MYSQL_DDL_catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1_2"},"is_ex$
```

root@ubuntu:

```
    /var/www/magento2# php -d memory_limit=8192M bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean
    Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
    Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:49
    Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:56
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5893-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_idx` SELECT catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`entity_id`,
catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`customer_group_id`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`website_id`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`tax_class_id`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`orig_price` AS `price`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`price` AS `final_price`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`min_price`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`max_price`, catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`tier_price` FROM catalog_product_index_price_final_idx
```

My database table "cron_schedule"
show message :

```
indexer_update_all_views
Can't create directory /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/.
indexer_reindex_all_invalid
Can't create directory /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/.
indexer_update_all_views
Can't create directory /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/.
indexer_reindex_all_invalid
Can't create directory /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/.
magento_newrelicreporting_cron
Class Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\CollectionFactory does not exist
Can't create directory
sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails
/var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Translate/ResourceInterface/.
Can't create directory
 sales_send_order_shipment_emails
/var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Translate/ResourceInterface/.
Can't create directory
sales_send_order_invoice_emails
/var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Translate/ResourceInterface/.
Can't create directory
sales_send_order_emails
/var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Translate/ResourceInterface/.
indexer_update_all_views
Can't create directory /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/.
indexer_reindex_all_invalid
Can't create directory /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/Processor/.
```

Comment: You added new product via CSV file?

Comment: Yes, import product via CSV file.

Comment: After importing with Csv file, product showed properly? And then, after re-indexing, product didn't display?

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '5893-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price_idx` SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx`.`entity_id`,

Comment: reset the indexes and then try again

Answer (score 0):

In the admin got to System->Cache Management, select all cache types and refresh them. Then reload your shop page. Should be there then.

If this does not help, check your products stock. Are your products active, in stock and if you use magento´s stock management make sure you set the stock amount > 0.

PS: The log outputs you posted look fine! At least that is how they look most of the time in magento even in 100% running shops.

Comment: Before the products are displayed, now the index is broken , I have no problem setting product, before or displayed.

Comment: How do you know the index is broken? Did you get an error message?

Comment: use cli   bin/magento indexer:reindex && php bin/magento cache:clean,display  index has been rebuilt successfully in 0:00 ,But , Don't display product , I cleaned cache .

Comment: Did you check that you import was used with the correct stock settings?

Comment: yes, but ,don't  diplayed products.

Comment: Can you export a single product and post this here?

Comment: I use mysql query,  UPDATE indexer_state SET status = 'valid';

Comment: What happens if you do that? Are products shown then?

Comment: You Need to fix the Duplicate entry error. Did your import succeed without any errors? Did you use the magneto product import? Looks like you got two entries with 5893-0-1. Usually the import throws an error and doesn't complete unless you set the numbers of errors to ignore very high or you directly imported your data into the do using sql.

Comment: I deleted 5893 product .  but , reindex long time

Answer (score 0):

First re-index data using Command Prompt

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After this use below content Deploy command.

```
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -dmemory_limit=6g  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then Check it works.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues open issues on Magento Github

[#3507](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3507)

[#5627](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5627)

All of these issues are closed but without solution yet.

If you are now using these blocks I recomended to "reorder" following the instruction or just remove it.

Comment: Please add what version release fixes those bugs, it greatly improves the value of the site, for anyone trying to fix a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands again:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy(if this command don't work than try this: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f)

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

if it doesn't help then check your directory writes and try running below command in your root magento directory:

```
chmod -R 0777 pub var generated
```

And also check quantity and stock status of your products.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the indexes are corrupted,
Try first resetting the indexes for the price or better for the whole catalog:

**bin/magento indexer:reset**

**bin/magento indexer:reindex**

This should clear all the indexes and redo all of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for re-indexing externally.

```
<?php 
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php'; 
    set_time_limit(0); 
    $status = "";
    $params = $_SERVER;
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $indexer = $obj->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory')->create();
    $ids = $indexer->getAllIds();
    if(isset($_GET["index"])){  
        $indexerId = $_GET["index"];
        $indexer = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
        $indexer->reindexAll($indexerId); // this reindexes all     
        //$status = 'Succesfully Reindexed - '.$indexerId;   
        header( "Location:/reindex_core.php?status=1" );   
    } 

    if(isset($_GET["reset"])){  
        $indexerId = $_GET["reset"];
        $indexer = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexerId);
        $state = $indexer->getState();
        $state->setStatus(\Magento\Framework\Indexer\StateInterface::STATUS_INVALID);
        $state->save(); 
        //$status = 'Succesfully resetted - '.$indexerId;
        header( "Location:/reindex_core.php?status=1" );        
    }

    if(isset($_GET["status"])){ 
        $status = 'Successfully done !!!';
    } 

    ?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>EST Reindexer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="reindexerBlock">
<h1><a href="/reindex_core.php">Reindexer</a></h1>
<?php if($status): ?>
<p class="alert"><?php echo $status; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Indexer Name</th>
    <th>Click to Reindex</th> 
    <th>Current Status</th>
    <th>Click to Reset</th>     
  </tr>  
  <?php foreach ($ids as $id) { 
    $indexer = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($id); ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
      <td><a class="statusButton" href="?index=<?php echo $id; ?>">Reindex</a></td> 
      <?php switch ($indexer->getStatus()) {
        case 'valid':
            $style = "green";
            break;      
        default:
            $style = "red";
            break;
      } ?>      
      <td><a class="statusButton" style="background-color:<?php echo $style; ?>">Status: <?php echo $indexer->getStatus(); ?></a></td>
      <td><a onclick="resetChecker()" class="resetChecker statusButton" style="background-color:#ec2029" href="?reset=<?php echo $id; ?>">Reset</a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
<style> 
td { 
    padding: 10px; font-size: 18px;
}

.statusButton {
  background-color: black; 
  border: 2px solid blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.reindexerBlock{
    width: 1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
<script>
function resetChecker(){  
  var r = confirm("Sure you want to reset?");
  if (r !== true){
    event.preventDefault();
  }  
}
</script>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```